# Missing log entries by using SocketAppender of logback

Tags: sockets, logging, logback

I'm using Logback SSLSocketAppender to direct logs into a central logger server. The application is running ok, and I can see the logs being received on the server side.

However, a close look at the logs, usually out of every 5 log entries, there is 1 or 2 dropped . According to [Logback Doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html), TCP protocol should guarantee an eventual consistency of the logs, but not in my case.

> SocketAppender operates above the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) layer which provides a reliable, sequenced, flow-controlled end-to-end octet stream. Consequently, if the remote server is reachable, then log events will eventually arrive there. Otherwise, if the remote server is down or unreachable, the logging events will simply be dropped. If and when the server comes back up, then event transmission will be resumed transparently. This transparent reconnection is performed by a connector thread which periodically attempts to connect to the server.

Wondering anyone had similar issues before?

Thanks!

-----  Edit -----

I did an experiment to confirm it:

```
int i = 0 ;
while (i < 10000) {
    log.info(i + " : =======");
    i ++;
}
```

And on the sever side, the received log looks like:

```
2013-09-12 17:59:09,174 INFO  [main]  - 0 : =======
2013-09-12 17:59:09,175 INFO  [main]  - 5 : =======
2013-09-12 17:59:09,175 INFO  [main]  - 10 : =======
2013-09-12 17:59:09,176 INFO  [main]  - 13 : =======
2013-09-12 17:59:09,177 INFO  [main]  - 17 : =======
2013-09-12 17:59:09,178 INFO  [main]  - 21 : =======
```

And If I try it a second time, the logged message will be different.

Comment: Is there a pattern to it? For example, are certain types/categories not being sent to the central log? Or, do you see some logged message one time and then an almost identical message does not get there the next time?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no pattern with it, any message could drop. I have updated my question above with more details. Thanks @DariusX.

Comment: Never seen this happen. We have about 14 or 15 nodes that log to a central socket-server. I assume there are no filters on the appender specified either on the nodes that are sending, or in the config of the socket-server. (e.g. DuplicateSuppressFilter)

Answer (score 1):

http://logback.qos.ch/news.html states that Logback 1.1.1 includes a fix for dropped events related to SocketAppender.